# Signal modulation with VNA

Tags: rf, modulation, vna

I want to apply a 1 V, 1 MHz signal to my DUT (coaxial waveguide) while sweeping the frequency from 300 kHz to 6 GHz by the VNA.

Right now, I applied the signal by the signal generator to the bias tee built in the VNA and it filters the signal, however, if I apply 5 kHz instead of 1 MHz, signal modulation successfully happened. You can see the details in [this video](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/14iw6hbi9p50vo9/AAAQS77HYBmNI0Pthhe9SKpBa?dl=0).

Is there any way that I can use passive devices like a separate bias tee or diplexer or couplers, or any other method that I can apply to these two signals simultaneously as a signal modulation?

Here is the schematic of the bis tee built in the VNA:

[image]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you expect the s-parameters of the device to depend on the presence of other signals?

Comment: @ThePhoton based on my project currently I need to apply a constant frequency and sweeping frequencies simultaneously. it seems it is kind of like a signal modulation. how can I apply these two signals simultaneously?

Comment: Why are you using a VNA then? You can just use a sweeping synthesizer for about 1/10 the cost of a VNA.

Comment: because i have to measure the sparamters too.